# do serialization with c++ fstream

Tags: c++, serialization, io, stream, std

I try to do serialization with fstream. The stream syntax is: 
"IndexLengthDataIndexLengthData...". e.g., 11c22cc33ccc. When reading the file, the input stream will read "11" as a whole for index.

The index is within [1, INT_MAX]. The length is limited to 516.

Can I do this without using a separator.e.g, "@" or "#", between index and length?

```
int main() {
  std::ofstream ofs;
  ofs.open("myfile.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);
  for(int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
    ofs << i; // for index
    ofs << i; // for length
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) ofs << 'c';
  }
  ofs.close();
  std::ifstream ifs;
  ifs.open("myfile.txt", std::ifstream::in);
  for (int i = 0; !ifs.eof() && ifs.good(); ++i) {
    int index = 0, length = 0;
    ifs >> index;
    ifs >> length;
    std::cout << "index is " << index << "length is " << length << std::endl;
    // Jump to the next entry
    ifs.seekg(length, std::ios_base::cur);
  }
}
```

Comment: Only if your index is only a single digit.  You need a fixed length index and a fixed length length field and then pad the data with zeros.

Comment: no, the index is not single digit. it could be a value of any integer greater than 0.

Comment: If `IndexLength` contains `1234` what is the value of `Index` and the value of `Length`:  1, 234 or 12, 34 or 123, 4?

Comment: You glue together index and length and expect C++ to magically find out where the invisible seam is, and unglue it. Won't happen.

Comment: You will need a token between the index and length or they will need to be fixed length fields. If storing them as binary is an option you can store an `uint32_t` and a `uint16_t`.

Comment: Why not just read the entire line into a string and parse it?  Trying to use a stream object to do this work is clumsy IMO.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, because I want to read/write it into a file.

Comment: @DavidThomas, how to do with fixed length? by setw()?

Comment: @pepero *because I want to read/write it into a file* -- I have no idea what that has to do with simply reading the data into a string, parsing it, and writing whatever you want back to a file.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, sorry, i misunderstood you. so you mean, it would be better to read it first into string and parse the string? but i think c++ stream class is convenient for parsing. no? e.g., how do you parse a string, most probably you make a stringstream out of it, then do extraction.

Comment: @pepero -- Your requirements (it would seem) go beyond what a stringstream or what a C++ stream is designed for.   If streams were so great, why is there parsing, regex, etc. classes developed?  Sometimes you have to do this yourself -- streams can do limited parsing, and anything beyond it needs to be done "by hand".

Comment: There's no difference (in context of separator need) between parsing it per char or per line as @PaulMcKenzie suggests. You will run into problem of index vs length end/start position anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you have fixed size formatting, so 10 chars for index, 3 chars for length, and your example would be encoded as:
`"         1  1c         2  2cc         3  3ccc"`.

Also you talk about `fstream`, but it looks like you are pursuing a text (human readable) serialization, not binary one. If that is the case, but you don't need truly human readable form, you can mark first byte of length with some bit (numbers in ASCII are encoded as `0x30` to `0x39` value, so you can for example set `0x40` bit without destroying data bytes. Then your example would look like:
`1qc2rcc3sccc` (`q` = `0x71` = `0x40|0x31` = `0x40|'1'`)

For some longer value it would look as: `113q00123456789` ... **ARGH** I wanted to serialize 10 chars long string "0123456789", and look what happened, I got length `100` instead of `10` (or even worse 100123456789, if you would not limit), so both start and end of length has to be tainted in some way, maybe using bit `0x80` to mark end of length.
`1\361c2\362cc3\363ccc` (`\361` = `0xF1` = `0x40|0x80|0x31` = `0x40|0x80|'1'`)

Longer value second try:
`113q°0123456789` (index 113, length 10, data "0123456789", `q` = `0x40|'1'`, `°` = `0x80|'0'`).

Don't you want rather binary form? Would be shorter.

---

BTW, if you don't mind tainting values, but you want to stay in 7bit ASCII, you can taint not start and end of length, but ends of both index and length, and only with `0x40`. So the `11c` would become `qqc`. And `113` `10` `0123456789` would be `11s1p0123456789`.

---

Binary write/read with platform agnostic endiannes (i.e. file written on little-endian will work on other platform with big-endian).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

/**
 * Writes index+length+data in binary form to "out" stream.
 * 
 * Returns number of bytes written to out stream.
 * 
 * Does no data validation (the variable types are only limits for input data).
 * 
 * writeData and readData are done in endiannes agnostic way.
 * So file saved at big-endian platform will be restored correctly on little-endian platform.
 **/
size_t writeData(std::ostream & out,
        const uint32_t index, const uint16_t length, const uint8_t *data) {
    // Write index and length bytes to out stream, resolve endiannes of host platform.
    out.put((char)((index>>0)&0xFF));
    out.put((char)((index>>8)&0xFF));
    out.put((char)((index>>16)&0xFF));
    out.put((char)((index>>24)&0xFF));
    out.put((char)((length>>0)&0xFF));
    out.put((char)((length>>8)&0xFF));
    // If any data, write them to stream
    if (0 < length) out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(data), length);
    return 4 + 2 + length;
}

/**
 * Read data from stream "in" stream into variables index, length and data.
 * 
 * If "in" doesn't contain enough bytes for index+length, zero index/length is returned
 * 
 * If "in" contains more than index+length bytes, but the data are shorter than length,
 * then "repaired" shorter data are returned with shorter "length" (not the read one).
 **/
void readData(std::istream & in,
        uint32_t & index, uint16_t & length, std::vector<uint8_t> & data) {
    // clear current values in index, length, data
    index = length = 0; data.clear();
    // read index+length header from stream
    uint8_t buffer[6];
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(buffer), 6);
    if (6 != in.gcount()) return;   // header data (index+legth) not found
    // Reassemble read bytes together to index/length numbers in host endiannes.
    index = (buffer[0]<<0) | (buffer[1]<<8) | (buffer[2]<<16) | (buffer[3]<<24);
    length = (buffer[4]<<0) | (buffer[5]<<8);
    if (0 == length) return;    // zero length, nothing more to read
    // Read the binary data of expected length
    data.resize(length);  // reserve memory for read
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(data.data()), length);
    if (length != in.gcount()) {    // data read didn't have expected length, damaged file?
        // TODO you may want to handle damaged data in other way, like returning index 0
        // This code will simply accept shorter data, and "repair" length
        length = in.gcount();
        data.resize(length);
    }
}
```

To see it in action, you may try it on [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/9375).

Comment: I sort of wonder why don't you simply add a separator (space)... so you would have `1 1 c2 2 cc3 3 ccc`. Just make sure you read full length content data, if there would be string with space included, like `56 11 hello world`.

Comment: yeah, just want to save some space. it is not necessary to be textual file. binary format is ok. it seems that these

Comment: @pepero: btw, this answer is a bit "mocking" of you. It doesn't make too much sense what you are asking for. If you want to save space, just add 7zip library to your project and run the stream trough compression (although from question it feels like that may be a bit complex for you, but that's different story, how much effort and learning you will put into it). And I would go for binary serialization, if the output does not need to be human readable and index,length are often longer than 1-2chars (32b int is 4B long). So this answer is just show-of, that it **can** be done without separator.

Comment: @pepero I added the binary example. It would be still nice to run this trough compression, to save size further. If you are curious how 0x40 marker code would look, I may write the interesting parts of it too, but only if you think it may teach you something, and you will study it (too much waste time just for showing it without good reason).

Comment: i was wondering about marking the end of length. since the following data part could contain anything, so the length probably has to be fixed. e.g. length 1~9: 0xF1~0xF9; length 10~99: 0x71 0xF0 ~ 0x79 0xF9; length 100~999: 0x71 0x70 0xF0 ~ 0x79 0x79 0xF9

Comment: thanks a lot! i understand it better now. I will try your example code, and keep you updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118355/discussion-between-ped7g-and-pepero).